# sorting csv file based on multiple columns

Tags: java, csv

I need to sort a csv file based on multiple columns.
Say my csv consists of 15 fields,I have to sort them on the basis of 4 columns combination.I need to sort my file by 2nd column, then by 3rd ,then  4th and then by 1st column.

How can I achieve this using Java? Can I use any open source library for it?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have you extracted all the data from your csv file to an array/several lists/stack/custom object ?

Comment: Why do you need Java? Linux sort could do that easily

Comment: Sorting I need as in between step for my large project , so linux sort can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely read the csv using [open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and then sort it using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) methods. You will need to create your own comparator, but it is easily testable unitarily.

The real trick is: how big is your csv? The method I described requires to store everything in memory, so if your csv is not too big it will work.

It's a question of the size of the CSV files in bytes.
if your csv is about 40k rows and 15 columns, and provided your data in every 
column is around 100 words long, it should represent 40*1000 rows *15 columns *100 (= I assume columns are around 100 characters each on average) bytes =~ 60MB in memory.

Any modern computer/server will handle that easily. if you have very long strings in your columns, like 1000 character strings it should still work.
Now if the size of the files to sort increases dramatically it won't work anymore.

You should start worrying if the files to process exceeds 500MB.

Comment: Thx for your response , my csv file consists of around 30-40k rows.For how much rows , would you recommend this solution?